# Getting the colour of where you have clicked on a JPanel?

Tags: java, colors, click, jpanel, mouse-listeners

I only want a method to activate if the pixel that is clicked is white. How would I implement this? Trying to look for a method that returns the colour at a coord, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. If you have got a [BufferedImage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) (or some other Image) you can use its `getRGB` methods (or `getRaster().getPixel`). If you haven't, you can use JPanel's `createImage` methods and use the returned image to get the pixel data.