# Getting pixel value on specified coordinates in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Is there any method in java like the one in c++ that is int getPixel(x,y), it will return the pixel value at x,y coordinate. I want the same thing to do in java. Currently i am drawing lines in JPanel and want to get the value of some specified pixel. I have checked the function of Robot class but it will not be helpful in my case.

Thanks in advance for help and suggestions.

Comment: Here is a similar question already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623351/getting-the-colour-of-where-you-have-clicked-on-a-jpanel

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have done it AL-HAMDULILLAH.